# workbooks.close does not work for me

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hope someone can help with my following problem.

I want to make sure a specific workbook is closed before It gets an update.
for that I was planning to start with.

`Private Sub Command1_Click()
workbooks("workbookname.XLSM").close Savechanges = False
End Sub`

I also tried

`workbooks("workbookname.Xlsm").close`

Both i have run separately and both give me Error code 9.

The specific file will always be on the desktop of the user.

I thought it might have something to do with my references so I checked and have the following references turned on. (some for other specific reasons).

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
- Microsoft Excel 16.0
- Object Library Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Really hope someone can help me with this. I've been surfing quite a large number of forums but no where i could find the same problem or solution.

w.k.r. Drac.

Comment: If this code runs in Access, you can't do `workbooks("foo").bar`. You must use your Excel Application object, e.g. `objExcel.Workboks(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check to see if it's open, and reference the open object properly. The function below (which I picked up off SO somewhere), returns a true/false value about the file in particular:

You would use it as such:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim xls As Object

If IsWorkBookOpen("C:/Users/Desktop/Workbook.xlsm") = True Then
    Set xls = GetObject("C:/Users/Desktop/Workbook.xlsm")
    xls.Close True
Else
    'do stuff if closed
End If

End Sub
```

Function:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Erin, thank you for looking into this for me and offering a possible solution. I just tried this and your code does exactly what it is supposed to do for me. yet when i get a True value it still gives the error when trying to execute my line.

Comment: Try referencing using the GetObject function. Still a runtime error 9?

Comment: On the other hand this gives me the option to give the user a warning to close it himself :) I think ill do that for now. Thanks !

Comment: Hello Erin, That did actually close something. now only Excel is still open but no workbook inside it. no error though

Comment: Yeah, it only closes the file referenced, not the excel application in case the user has other files open as well.

Comment: I think I can work with that. thanks a lot for your time and help.